# Trouble parsing nested JSON in Swift 5 using Decodable

Tags: json, swift

I have an API which returns JSON structured similarly to the one below. For simplicity purposes, I've taken out all of the siblings dictionaries within the JSON so we can focus on the core goal of parsing a single property. I can't seem to figure out why it won't parse.

API JSON:

```
{
    "players": {
        "uniqueUUIDwouldGoHere": {
            "ace": {
                "operatorpvp_kills": 11
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Swift Structs are written like:

```swift
public struct opsResponse: Decodable {
    var players : [String: opsInner]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case players = "players"
    }
}
public struct opsInner: Decodable {
    var ace : [String: ace]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ace = "ace"
    }
}

public struct ace: Decodable {
    var operatorpvp_kills : Int = 0
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case operatorpvp_kills = "operatorpvp_kills"
    }
}
```

And lastly, the URLSession decoder portion:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let json = try decoder.decode(opsResponse.self, from: data)
```

Error Message from `catch`:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "players", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "uniqueUUIDwouldGoHere", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "ace", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "operatorpvp_kills", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I changed:
`var ace : [String: ace]`
to
`var ace : ace`